# Is this the correct way to update a state based on the previous state in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Here's my code:

```
  const [val, setVal] = useState(0);

  function onClick() {
    setVal(val + 1);
  }
```

I just wanted to check if this is the correct way to update a state based on a previous state? Why/why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfectly fine approach. Note that you could also get the value of your current state as a callback parameter on `setVal`, e.g.: `setVal(prevState => prevState + 1)`.

Just be careful when manipulating arrays or objects since they shouldn't be directly mutated (with methods such as `push` or `pop` etc).